# handling meteor.call behaviour

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

This is more of a doubt than an actual problem, but as a programming student I'm curious about this:
In my project I have this "text to input to text" element, which allows fast edition of the user profile:

Template:

```
<template name="profile">
  <h3>Your Profile</h3>

  <div>
    {{#with userProfile}}
        <p><span>Name: </span> <span class="editableContentSolid" id="editableProfileName"> {{username}}{{#unless username}}No name!!!{{/unless}}</span></p>
        <p><span>eMail: </span> <span>{{emails.[0].address}}</span></p>
    {{/with}}
  </div>
</template>
```

With these events:

```
Template.profile.events({
    'click .editableContentSolid' : function(event) {
            var html = $(event.target).text().trim();
            var editableText = 
                $("<input class='editableContentFluid' id='editableProfileName' type='text' placeholder='"+html+"'>");
            editableText.val(html);
            $(event.target).replaceWith(editableText);

            $("#editableProfileName").val(html);
            editableText.focus();
    },
    'blur .editableContentFluid' : function(event) {        
        var html = $(event.target).val();       
        var viewableText = $("<span class='editableContentSolid' id='editableProfileName'></span>");

        if (html == "") {
            viewableText.html(Meteor.user().username);
            $(event.target).replaceWith(viewableText);
        } else {
            viewableText.html(html);
            Meteor.call("isUser",html, function(error,result) {
                if(error) {
                    Bert.alert("Name already in use","warning");
                    viewableText.html(Meteor.user().username);
                    $(event.target).replaceWith(viewableText);
                } else {
                    Meteor.users.update({_id:Meteor.user()._id}, {$set:{username:html}});
                    $(event.target).replaceWith(viewableText);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And finally the method call:

```
isUser : function(nameOrMail) {
        if (! Meteor.userId()) {
            throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
        }
        check(nameOrMail, String);

        var member = Accounts.findUserByUsername(nameOrMail);
        if (!member) {
            member = Accounts.findUserByEmail(nameOrMail);
        }

        if (!member) {
            return true;
        } else if(member) {
            throw new Meteor.error("user-already-exists");
        }
    }
```

It is working fine, and no errors are displayed in the client, however the meteor console throws and error when I enter an existing username: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftx4q.png

Also, is there a better way to deal with the error/success stuff with the meteor calls? And is it correct to just return true on success?

Comment: What do you mean by "member" being uninitialized? You initialize that variable in "isUser". Also which error does it throw?

Comment: error: https://i.imgur.com/tVXaLs4.png (it happens only when I insert an existing username)

Comment: ok, checking it again, the odd behaviour was a mistake of me reading bad the log, I'm gonna fix the answer

Comment: Er... isn't that the `check(nameOrMail, String);` line of code?

Comment: check works, the line the console error points to is the "throw new Meteor.error("user-already-exists");" maybe it is just that, I'm throwing an error so I get that log?

Comment: Your stack trace points to the "check". I suspect "nameOrMail" is undefined. You can use `console.log` to find it out.

Comment: console.log(typeof(nameOrMail)); prints string. I just tried reversing the code; now the event, if there's an error on the Meteor.call, shows the alert and gets the old name, and if there's a result it updates the collection and shows the new name, and I also inverted the if conditionals on the isUser method so if it finds the member it returns as success, and throws an error if not, now of course the log error appears when I insert a name that is not in use, so I think it is just the standard error log for the throw Meteor.error line